# How to return the values between two elements of a list as a new list

Tags: python

I have the following list :

```
['[SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]', 'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', '[/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]']
```

Is there a way to return only the value between [SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping][/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping] as a list, but searching between two keywords, not by intex, resulted list :

```
'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
In [1995]: l = ['[SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]', 'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29
      ...:  = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DO
      ...: C_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'start
      ...: Datex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', '[/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]'] 
      ...:  

In [1993]: from_index = l.index('[SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]') 
      ...: to_index = l.index('[/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]')                                                                                                                                              

In [1994]: l[from_index + 1:to_index]                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[1994]: 
['lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>',
 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>',
 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>',
 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>',
 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>',
 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>',
 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>',
 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>',
 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>',
 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>',
 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>',
 'nationalId = CNP<move>',
 'company = COMPANY<move>',
 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>',
 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>',
 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile
oldlist = ['[SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]', 'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', '[/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]']
newlist = list(takewhile(lambda x: x!='[/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]', dropwhile(lambda x: x!='[SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]', oldlist))[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate over a list like this:

```
myList = ['[SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]', 'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', '[/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]']
startCounter = None
endCounter = None
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i] == '[SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]':
        startCounter = i
    if myList[i] == '[/SF_BUF_SAP_USERS_Mapping]':
        endCounter = i

print(myList[startCounter+1: endCounter])
```

Output:

```
['lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>']
```